# Measuring traffic with node.js http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, bandwidth, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I wrote a small reverse proxy for hosting my applications on the same computer using http and node-http-proxy modules. For example:

I have:

- **proxy** running on port 80
- **website1.com** running on port 3000
- **website2.com** running on port 3001
- **website3.com** running on port 3002

If I access the **website1.com** domain, the proxy will serve the contents from server running on port 3000 using **node-http-proxy**.

But now I need to measure the bandwidth used for each domain (both incoming/outgoing, or at least outgoing)

I've tried listening for 'data' events on request object, but in documentation they said that readable events isn't emitted on **IncomignMessage** for some reason.

I wrote a little module for the "base" functionality too, it can be found here:

https://npmjs.org/package/reproxy

See **example/example.js**

So, how can I accomplish this measure, using the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was setting and 'end' event on RoutingProxy object and grabbing the socket information in the event callback.

```
var proxy = new require('http-proxy').RoutingProxy();

proxy.on('end', function(req, res, response) {

    var host = req.headers.host;
    var bytesIn = response.socket._bytesDispatched;
    var bytesOut = response.socket.bytesRead;

    console.log('request to ' + host);
    console.log('request:  ' + bytesIn + ' bytes.');
    console.log('response: ' + bytesOut + ' bytes.');

});
```

Note that this is not optimal solution, because the request size includes the headers added by the reverse proxy, such as "x-" headers.

Comment: I have written s very similar app and this is honna help me!

Comment: As I said, this is not the optimal solution since it adds more "bytes" because of the proxy header, but it works.

Comment: Yes sure, you are right. Since my app is just for learning (and not for production use) its ok!